# IBM Process designer integration with Subversion

Tags: svn, ibm-bpm

I need to be integrating IBM process designer with subversion.  I need to version control the BPM activities as well as take the binary for the complete build in jenkins.

Can anyone tell me if you have had version controlled IBM process designer with Subversion?

Comment: @Braiam why did you create a new tag instead of using [ibm-bpm]?

Comment: @Braiam, I re-tagged the four questions with [ibm-bpm].

Comment: @JoshMc because [business process management] exist and it's being used for these questions.

Comment: @Braiam, what I mean is that tag [ibm-bpm] already existed with with 144 questions and has at least a little tag info associated with it.  The tag  [ibm-business-process-management] looks like it was created with only 4 of the questions you re-tagged from the more generic tag [business-process-management].  I agree with the re-tag, but just thought it should be to the existing tag so I went ahead and re-tagged them.

Comment: @Braiam on a 5th question I just removed  [ibm-business-process-management] and left [ibm-bpm] as it had both.  There are now no questions in the [ibm-business-process-management] and it should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The philosophy of IBM BPM solutions is that they are 100% maintained within the IBM BPM Process Center environment.  All artifacts ... literally everything ... is maintained within the Process Center and there is no way to "check it out" or otherwise access it.  The model is that there are no "files" of artifacts and hence there is nothing to place under source code control of any other source code management system.

There is also no "build system".  When one saves artifacts from within Process Designer, they are immediately accessible from a Process App for unit testing.  Only when one wishes to deploy to the production of QA would one export a solution as a ZIP file and install it in a Process Server environment.  Even then, if Process Servers have network connectivity to Process Center, the deployment of the solution can be direct without any intermediate exports of files.

The bottom line answer is that IBM's philosophy here is not "classic" edit/save/compile/test but is rather an edit/save/test with everything tracked by Process Center.

Answer (score 0):

subversion has already existed in the process designer when you make any changes and save it commit on Process Center repository, for integration designer also made the same when you save and click on project